# Creating custom lexicon from the column of dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to make a custom lexicon for text analysis using python. I have a data frame with the binary categorization of emotion. If the value is 1, I want to put the column name in the lexicon for each row and wrap them with ['column name']. For example,

I have a sample data frame as below:

```
en  Positive    Negative    Anger   Anticipation    Disgust Fear    Joy Sadness Surprise    Trust
abacus  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
abandon 0   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
abandoned   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
```

Expected output is:

```
{'abacus': ['trust'], 'abandon': ['fear', 'negative', 'sadness'],
               'abandoned': ['anger', 'fear', 'negative', 'sadness']}
```

Could it be any way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `lambda` function on each row and then convert the result to a `dict` like so:

```
>>> data.apply(lambda x: list(data.columns[x==1]), axis=1).to_dict()
{'abacus': ['Trust'],
 'abandon': ['Negative', 'Fear', 'Sadness'],
 'abandoned': ['Negative', 'Anger', 'Fear', 'Sadness']}
```